# How to pass data from by Android speech recognizer to a service?

Tags: android, android-intent, speech-recognition

I have a widget which will open the default speech recognizer activity on click. Now I want the data from this activity to go to my service which does some processing. I can start the speech recognizer activity using the following code

```
    @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            MicWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.mic_widget_layout);

         // this intent points to activity that should handle results
         Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,
         SpeechWidgetService.class);
         // this intent wraps results activity intent
         PendingIntent resultsPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
         context, REQUEST_CODE, serviceIntent, 0);

        // this intent calls the speech recognition
        Intent voiceIntent = new Intent(
                RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Jarvis");
        voiceIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT,
                resultsPendingIntent);

        // this intent wraps voice recognition intent
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                REQUEST_CODE, voiceIntent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.arc_widget, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "clicking..");
}
```

When I click on the widget, everything works fine and I can speak and it closes when I stop speaking. The problem is that the service is not at all being called. What am I doing wrong? For now I just have a dummy service to check whether data is coming in or not.

```
public class SpeechWidgetService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "SpeechWidgetService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    ArrayList<String> voiceResults = intent.getExtras().getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS); 
    Log.d(TAG, voiceResults.get(0));
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), voiceResults.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind i figured it out. You will have to place an additional dummy activity, fire it from the widget and call the speech recognizer from there. You can always get back the result using onActivityResult().

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't need a dummy activity.
This could be a problem related to the request code for the PendingIntent.
See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63666 for a bug report which could be related to your problem

Did you try to use another request code?